# Converting strange coordinates from shapefile into regular lat and long using GeoTools?

Tags: shapefile, coordinate-system, java, geotools

I use this dataset from the European Union:
http://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/administrative-land-accounting-units

Opening the shapefile with Java' Geotools, I see coordinates like:

```
4591000 2713000
```

and I would need to translate these into regular lat and long coordinates.

I've seen posts suggesting the .prj file can help solving this problem, so I post its content here:

```
PROJCS
["ETRS_1989_LAEA",GEOGCS["GCS_ETRS_1989",DATUM["D_ETRS_1989",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Azimuthal_Equal_Area"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",4321000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",3210000.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",10.0],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",52.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
```

I am not a specialist of GIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dataset use [Pan-European mapping standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_grid) projection system - [EPSG3035](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/etrs89-etrs-laea/)

If you are open to non-java tool and **simplicity**, you will be able to reproject the file to [WGS84](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System) using GDAL/OGR  : http://www.gdal.org/, that way :

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" path/to/NUTSV9_LEAC.shp NUTSV9_LEAC_wgs84.shp -s_srs EPSG:3035 -t_srs EPSG:4326
```

Comment: great, I'll do that. Geotools seems to have the capability to do that too, but that looks complicated: http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/referencing/crs.html

Comment: Yes, it is possible but a bit more complicated

Answer (score 0):

For on-line transformation/convertion use [Mygeodata Converter](http://converter.mygeodata.eu).